# Extract numbers from a comma separated list using excel formula and perform a lookup

Tags: excel

**In MS Excel, a List of commas separated numbers**

In a column, I have a text string number list ( up to four numbers) that represent row numbers in a table ( 'MyTable' in another worksheet). These numbers are entered by a user, that looks like the example list below:

23,234,2,16

**The Goal using MS Excel**

My goal, in the next column, is to perform and concatenate a lookup of each row number in the above list from a table.

E.g. Vlookup(23,MyTable,2,)&Vlookup(234,MyTable,7,) etc.

**My question: The Challenge**

In excel, I need a formula to extract from the comma separated list above, each number in turn and use it as the lookup value in a series of concatenated `VLOOKUP` formulae as shown above. The list can contain between one and four numbers.

Comment: You need to show your own research, invested effort and a concrete problem. Please no "solve my entire problem for me" questions.

Comment: You are looking in two different column 2 and 7 in your formula, how do we know from which column to pull the data?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put the string in a cell. Use **Data->Text to columns**. That will split this data into 4 columns. If you want it vertically stacked, you can copy it, **Paste Special->Transpose**.
2. Then, you can apply VLOOKUP over that. If you do want wish to transpose, HLOOKUP will work for you.